# Testing inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I am doing JS excercise (no jQuery or any other JS library) where I am supposed to create a simple game that starts by chosing number of players, name of each player and whether a player is a dealer or not. There can be only one dealer for each game:

```
var playersArray = [];
var playerNumber = prompt('Number of players?');

function player(playerName, playerDealer) //creating player object
{
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.playerDealer = playerDealer; 
    }

for (i=0;i < playerNumber; i++) //creating instances of player object and adding them into playersArray[]
{
    var j = i + 1;
    var inputName = prompt('Name of player '+j);
    var inputDealer = prompt ('Is '+inputName+' also dealer? (yes/no)');
        playersArray[i] = new player(inputName, inputDealer);     
}
```

I need to include a simple test into the loop that would check if the dealer has been appointed. How do I do that? How do I iterate through all instances of 'player', check if one of the property `playersArray[].playerDealer` is equal 'yes' and if so, how can I let player know ('You can't appoint more than one dealer') and return him back into the loop?

Comment: `For loop`, `if` statement, `continue` if theres already a dealer. Look them up, you'll learn more from it than others doing your homework for you.

Comment: `var dealerIsAppointed = false; for (...` and then set it to `true` inside.

Comment: Yes and skip the `prompt` and use `confirm`

Comment: Add variable before your prom named `dealerAssigned` with a value of false, run a for loop before your prompt that loops through your players array. When it hits a `playerDealer == true`, then set `dealerAssigned` to `true` and `break`the loop. After this loop, add an `if` statement that says `if(dealAssigned){ alert("already assigned"); continue;}`. Now go and look up all this stuff and try again.

Comment: I didn't figure it out anyway:-)...thanks anyway and sorry for asking elementary questions. I know this isn't the right forum for this.

Comment: @somethinghere - I am sorry for getting back to this but I am so confused by your answer and just can't get my head around this. I've tried all possible solutions I could think of and none of them worked. Can you please specify how exactly should the second loop look like? I also don't understand how I test if `playerDealer == true` within this second loop as console keeps telling me that the playersArray is undefined...

Comment: @DDEX I don't know what you were doing, so I've posted an in-detail answer explaining what I'm doing. I hope it helps and am glad that you tried a little bit. I try to explain everything so its clear how it works and why. I've also built in some failsafes, catching problems that might occur. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh... Here goes, at least you tried. I have made some tiny adjustments to make it easier to parse, and added a couple of things as failsafes for user input (user are unpredictable and might input stuff you don't want them to input, so these make sure you get a correct end result). I've also added some notes in the comments on what would be even better, so be sure to have a look at those.

```
var playersArray = [];
/* We want to be sure the user enters a number here, 
 * so we start by entering a non-number 
 * as our value so we can check later if it now IS a number. */
var playerNumber = "not-yet-determined";
/* Now let's use a while loop! While the following expression
 * evaluates 'false' (and NaN (not-a-number) is considered false!),
 * keep prompting the user to enter a number. */
while(!Number(playerNumber)){
    playerNumber = prompt('Number of players? (numerical)');
}

function player(playerName, playerDealer){
    this.playerName = playerName;
    /* We would like the following to be a boolean, 
     * because its either on or off. 
     * It might actually be better to use 
     * `playerDealer.indexOf("y") >= 0` so the user can also answer with
     * 'y' instead of typing the entire word, but I digress.
     * It might also be best to use .toLowerCase() on the word
     * to avoid some pedantic users typing 'Yes'. But again, I digress. */
    this.playerDealer = playerDealer == "yes" ? true : false; 
}

for (i = 0; i < playerNumber; i++){
    var inputName = prompt('Name of player #'+ (i + 1));
    /* Lets check if the dealer is already set.
     * We do this by creating a variable that will be stored
     * right here. We could also store the variable outside the
     * function (globally) and instead of looping below here, just
     * flip it to true when the dealer get assigned. */
    var dealerAssigned = false;
    /* Then we start looping (with a different variable than i!)) */
    for(var o = 0; o < playersArray.length; o++){
        /* If theres an instance of playerDealer that evaluates to
         * 'true', then assign true to our variable. */
        if(playersArray[o].playerDealer){
            dealerAssigned = true;
            /* Because we know there is only one dealer, 
             * break the loop here. This is to prevent the 
             * loop from continuing, which is good practise since
             * a very large loop can hang your system for a while. */
            break;
        }
    }
    /* Lets only ask if the dealer is assigned when 
     * we know you can assign him. Otherwise we'll default to no.
     * However, since you want to let the user know, you could
     * add the following line: 
     * if(dealerAssigned){
     *     alert("Dealer is already assigned and cannot be reassigned!");
     * }
     */
    var inputDealer = !dealerAssigned
       ? prompt ('Is ' + inputName + ' also dealer? (yes/no)')
       : "no";
    /* Just for the record, you might want to consider using 
     * `push()` here: 
     * playersArray.push(new player(inputName, inputDealer));*/
    playersArray[i] = new player(inputName, inputDealer);     
}
/* Lets verify everything worked. */
console.log(playersArray);
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually did what you describe here except that my second (nested) for loop looked like this `for (k=0;k<playerNumber;k++)` ...and I was getting `TypeError: playersArray[k] is undefined`. From your code I understand that I should have focused on the actual array length rather then on absolute number of players. I also found an alternative solution of the exercise using `if(dealerAssigned && inputDealer=='yes'){alert("already assigned"); playersArray[i] = new player(inputName, 'no');`. Thanks a lot for your time and effort. Your code with all the comments is really helpful.

Comment: You could also add a check to your for loop to check if `playersArray[k]` is `undefined`(`if(typeof playersArray[k] == "undefined") break;`) and ignore it, but using the arrays `length` is generally considered best practise.